# Permission denied in mounted volume in docker

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I'm mounting a volume from my local host in a docker container using docker-compose (added the `volumes` entry id docker-compose.yml)

This works well, but when I try to run py.test I get permission errors:

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/foo/bar/.coverage'` etc

Also, when I try to create the .coverage dir when I'm logged in to the container I get:

```
mkdir .coverage
mkdir: cannot create directory '.coverage': Permission denied
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Change the rights of the mount poin so that the docker service user can access it.

Comment: @ReneM. just chmod or chown also? I've tried adding write permissions but it didn't work.

Comment: Depends on the actual rights and ownership and under which user your docker service is running

Comment: This question should really include the docker-compose.yml lines for the volume mount, the permissions on the host, and the permissions/directory contents in the container (`ls -al`)

Comment: also, If you have selinux enabled try temporarily disabling it and see if that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything (like a volume mount) in the docker container as long as the Docker itself has the right permission. You should exec your container using following:

docker exec -it -u 0 Container_NAME /bin/bash

And then execute py.test, I just hope you're not doing su - to some user within py.test

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to the file context on that directory, try changing it to a 'sandbox' file:

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /foo/bar/
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and fixed it by adding a `chmod -R 777` in my Dockerfile (adapt 777 to your permissions but you need a read/write) on the root folder of my test package (foo/bar/ in your case). I made it recursive because I run my test coverage in my sub-folders as well.